# Join Según Case SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

Estoy haciendo una consulta SQL bastante compleja debido a la naturaleza poco normalizada de la base de datos del sistema. El flujo de la consulta es el siguiente.

Hago un `SELECT` de algunos campos de varias tablas que *joineo*.

Luego, según el valor que tiene uno de uno de estos campos `(A,B,C,D)` tengo que *joinear* con otra tabla. Por ejemplo, si es tipo `'A'` el Join será contra `CabecerasA` ,  si es `'B'` será contra `CabecerasB` y etcétera.

Quiero usar un `Switch Case`, pero no sabría cÓmo implementarlo. Pongo una consulta de ejemplo:

```
SELECT id , att1 , att2 , tipo
FROM Table1 inner Join Table2 on(...)
     inner Join Table3 on(...)
```

Según el valor del atributo `'tipo'` debo *joinear* ésta consulta con la tabla correspondiente.

¿Cómo debería aplicar mi `Switch Case`?

Comment: esto esta dentro de un SP?

Comment: No, estoy tratando de evitarlo, será necesario ?

Comment: ¿No es posible que generes tu consulta a partir de un lenguaje de programación?

Comment: Muy buena recomendación, quizas intente algo en node con sequelize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respuesta rápida: No se puede. El CASE funciona a nivel de los datos/columnas no participa en el FROM/JOIN. Lo que quieres hacer es básicamente varios LEFT JOIN según el valor de cada campo `tipo`

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.tipo, 
     ISNULL(t1.valor, t2.valor)
     FROM Table1 t1
     left Join Table2 t2 on (t2.tipo = t1.tipo)
     left Join Table3 t3 on (t3.tipo = t1.tipo)
```

O sea, no puedes escapar de agregar todos los left join correspondientes a cada `tipo` a menos que... utilices consultas separadas y las unas mediante el UNION

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.tipo, t2.valor
     FROM Table1 t1
     inner Join Table2 t2 on (t1.tipo = t2.tipo)
     where t1.tipo = 'A'

UNION 

SELECT t1.id, t1.tipo, t3.valor
     FROM Table1 t1
     inner Join Table3 t2 on (t1.tipo = t3.tipo)
     where t1.tipo = 'b'
```

Dependiendo de los datos una forma puede ser más "performante" que otra

Comment: Amé la palabra "performante" :)

Comment: Esos joins que están en la consulta son obligatorios, debe hacerlos siempre. y luego, segun el tipo, seguir joineando para un lado o para otro

Comment: @FederHico: Agregue los left join que se me habían olvidado en el copy/paste, no hay forma de agregar o no un JOIN a una consulta en función de un determinado dato de dicha consulta. O puede ser que no hubiera entendido tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de solucionarlo, es generado una consulta de forma dinámica, es decir, el *query* se va formando según todas aquellas condiciones con las que desees contar:

```
DECLARE @tipo CHAR
DECLARE @valor_Tipo VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @Select_SQL VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @FROM_SQL VARCHAR(1024)
DECLARE @WHERE_SQL VARCHAR(1024)

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(1024)

SET @tipo = 'A'
SET @valor_Tipo = '123'

SET @Select_SQL = 'SELECT id , att1 , att2 , tipo '
SET @FROM_SQL = 'FROM Tabla1 T1 '
SET @WHERE_SQL = 'WHERE ' + @tipo + '.tipo = ' + @valor_Tipo

IF @tipo = 'A' 
    SET @FROM_SQL += 'INNER JOIN CabeceraA A ON T.Id = A.Id '
ELSE IF @tipo = 'B' 
    SET @FROM_SQL += 'INNER JOIN CabeceraB B ON T.Id = C.Id '
ELSE IF @tipo = 'C' 
    SET @FROM_SQL += 'INNER JOIN CabeceraC C ON T.Id = C.Id '
ELSE 
    SET @FROM_SQL += 'INNER JOIN CabeceraD D ON T.Id = D.Id '

SET @SQL = @Select_SQL + @FROM_SQL + @WHERE_SQL

EXEC (@SQL)
```

En el ejemplo que estoy poniendo, se estaría recibiendo un `tipo A`, para lo cual, la salida del *script* generado sería lo siguiente:

```
SELECT id
    ,att1
    ,att2
    ,tipo
FROM Tabla1 T1
INNER JOIN CabeceraA A ON T.Id = A.Id
WHERE A.tipo = 123
```

Comment: Gracias, también voy a intentar hacer una 2da versión de la Query con SP para que sea, como dice @patriciomoracho , mas "performante"